# Da Vinci Resolve 16 on Ubuntu 20.04 grey / not previewing video issue

Tags: 20.04, davinci-resolve

I installed ubuntu today, run updates, installed drivers, rebooted, then installed ubuntu-restricted-extras 
and then installed daVinci Resolve 16 lite following this guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfcwKemtYfc

I ran into no issues intalling, in fact, contrary to this guide where he gets 1 error during deb generation, I got 0.

And it starts fine, but when I put .mp4 files into the "MASTER" folder they all show up grey with no on-hover preview. also click and dragging the master files to timeline, even though showing the green placeholder for a short time, does not actually work, the preview disappears, sometimes during drag and drop and the timeline remains empty.

although the files play just fine with totem, I cannot view any file with any of davinci's diverse methods.... basically I cannot edit video with it. it is unusable as is.

Has anyone had this issue and found a solution to it?

I have an asus tuf 504gd with 8 GB of ram and a NVIDIA 1050

the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested) is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using both Resolve 16 and Ubuntu. From what I can understand, your problem should not be related with the installation process but I think, with codecs. If nothing changed in the past months, the free version under Linux cannot process h264 or h265 codecs, nor mp3. so you have to convert them in order to import in DaVinci. I usually work with dnxhd codec and pcm for audio, after some surfing around. the only drawback is that you have to consider the huge amount of space the resulting videos will occupy on your hard drive.

If you have CUDA installed you can copy the below lines into an empty .sh file and run it from a console. It takes all the mp4 files in the present folder and converts them to mov that can be used in DaVinci. If you do not have CUDA you have to change the h264_cuvid decoder

```
for i in *.mp4;
    do name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
    echo $name;
    ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i $i -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hq -pix_fmt yuv422p -c:a pcm_s16le $name.mov;
done
```

Comment: thanks, how do you install cude (I have an nVidia graphic card)